# React Leaflet Change Color of GeoJSON Feature on Hover

Tags: react-leaflet

Can't seem to find a simple way to change the color of a feature when I hover over it.

Using react-leaflet wigh GeoJSON:

```
export default function BaseMap({ places }) {
  
  return (
    <MapContainer
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
      preferCanvas={true}
      renderer={bufferedRenderer}
    >

      {features.map((feature) => {

        const trailName = feature.properties.TRAIL_NAME_LOWER || "Trail Name";

        return (
          <GeoJSON key={feature.properties.fid} data={feature}>
            <Popup>
              <PopupInfo
                name={trailName}
                distance={feature.properties.TRAIL_LENGTH}
                id={feature.properties.fid}
              />
            </Popup>
            <Tooltip>{trailName}</Tooltip>
          </GeoJSON>
        );
      })}
      <LocationMarker />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Is there a simple way to say:

```
onHover: style
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `onEachFeature` function and then change the `fillColor` of the layer on `mouseover`

```
<GeoJSON 
    onEachFeature={(feature, layer) => {
      layer.on({
        mouseover: (e) => {
          e.target.setStyle({ fillColor: 'red' });
        },
      });
    }}
>
......
</GeoJSON>
```

Also, don't forget to add a `mouseout` event handler to revert back to previous color.

Comment: Thanks! Had to switch to "{color: 'red'}" as my GeoJSON features are lines.